Large area left on the map of Canada (7)
Clue: Large area left on the map of Canada (7).
Answer: ALBERTA.
Why? I can see that Alberta is "of Canada".

Attribution:  https://puzzles.standard.co.uk/ (Evening Standard Cryptic 5/29/2024)

A possible source is Evening Standard Cryptic for 5/29/2024 https://i.sstatic.net/5398m3FH.png

As you can see in the map below, Alberta is a Canadian province that is on the left side of a Canadian map.


Downvotes seem hasty here - it answers the question taken at face value as it's currently written. No word from the OP yet that this isn't merely a straight crossword clue instead of a cryptic with additional wordplay to be found...

the original puzzle appears to make heavy use of cryptic definitions, so I think the alberta clue is likewise one of those (and honestly a pretty poor one at that. the surface doesn't really scan - what would you forget to take off a map of canada?)

It seems like an &lit to me. The whole thing can describe Alberta. "Large area left" gives AL. I admit I run out of steam there, but RTA is the French version of Canada's postal codes, so you just need a BE in there somewhere.

I too thought that it might be an &lit, perhaps one where only an abbreviation is defined cryptically, but the postal abbreviation for Alberta is AB, not AL. (I guess the postal codes were designed to be unique among US states and Canadian provinces.) I now think that the clue might just be a cryptic definition.

I thought "left" might mean backwards, as Alberta contains the letters of area in reverse order (and "large" might mean the letters are spread out rather than adjacent). Do the remaining letters, LBT, have anything to do with a map?

(As an addendum to my earlier comment: That crossword has "Sin city (5)", so there probably isn't really any wordplay involved. Just a lazy cryptic clue.)
